# How to take the default style for a control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this issue that's been bothering me for days. I hope some of you can help me out.

Say, in a UserControl, I declare a default XML Namespace, using xmlns= "mainNameSpace". In the main Grid, I happen to need a ResourceDictionary for most of my controls. However, there's this one control that I need to take the default style as specified in mainNameSpace (instead of the style specified in ResourceDictionary).

I hope this question is not so basic and does not lack adequate research on my part. Anyway, please forgive me if so :). Cheers...

Here's the relevant code. I want the Button to inherit from mainNameSpace and not from someDictionary.

```
<UserControl xmlns= "mainNameSpace>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="someDictionary"/>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Button>

  </Grid>  
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Post the relevant code and XAML and a more specific explanation of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can add x:Key to style in ResourceDictionary and assign Style property only where you need it. Other controls will stay with default style